# How to test what is causing a delay on user login?

Tags: 13.10

As of recently, when I log into my account there is a delay of 20s where first a black screen appears and then I log in.

How can I see what is going on during the black screen? I am trying to find out which app is causing such a delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the log files in the `/var/log/lightdm/` directory.

Also if you have a modified `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file with a `session-setup-script` that can cause a delay.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your GRUB to display details of the boot process. 
Remove the "quit" from your grub (gedit /etc/default/grub) and run the update command (sudo update-grub)

Here my example without the quit parameter for 12.04.3

```
GRUB_FONT=/boot/grub/DejaVuSansMono.pf2
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

If the delay happen later (after GRUB boot process) this might not help you.

Comment: Yes, delay does not happen on boot. All is Ok until the login screen. Then when I log in, this delay occurs.